# Heatmaps with eye-tracking data (weighted 2D-density)

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to create a fixation maps where the weight of each fixation on the 2d density map is determined by its duration. As I understood, the `stat_density2d()` function accepts the weight argument but does not process it ([ggplot2 2d Density Weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530028/ggplot2-2d-density-weights))

Is there a way to go around this ?
Also, how could I smooth the granularity of the heatmaps? I must be missing something quite obvious here

```
#sample data
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
df <- data.frame(x=sample(0:1920, 1000, replace=TRUE), 
                 y=sample(0:1080, 1000, replace=TRUE), 
                 dur=sample(50:1000, 1000, replace=TRUE))

#what I have so far
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y =y)) +
  stat_density2d(geom='raster', 
                 aes(fill=..count.., alpha=..count..), contour=FALSE) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=dur), alpha=0.2, color="red") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="green", high="red") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0, 1) , guide="none") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a `ggplot2` user, but basically you want to estimate a weighted 2d-density and make an `image` out of it. Your [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13533867/6574038) indicates that `ggplot2::geom_density2d` internally uses `MASS::kde2d`, but which only computes unweighted 2d-densities.

### Inflate observations

Similar to *@AllanCameron*'s suggestion (but without the need to use `tidyr`) we could inflate the data frame simply by copying each row by the number of milliseconds duration,

```
dfa <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), times=df$dur), -3]
```

and calculate the `kde2d` by hand.

```
n <- 1e3

system.time(
  dens1 <- MASS::kde2d(dfa$x, dfa$y, n=n)  ## this runs a while!
)
#     user   system  elapsed 
# 2253.285 2325.819  661.632
```

The `n=` argument denotes the number of grid points in each direction, the greater we choose it, the smoother the granularity will look in the heatmap image.

```
system.time(
  dens1 <- MASS::kde2d(dfa$x, dfa$y, n=n)  ## this runs a while
)
#     user   system  elapsed 
# 2253.285 2325.819  661.632 

image(dens1, col=heat.colors(n, rev=TRUE))
```

[image]

This almost runs forever, though with `n=1000`...

### Weighted 2d density estimation

In a comment on the answer mentioned above, [*@IRTFM* links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530028/ggplot2-2d-density-weights#comment45091311_13533867) an ancient *r-help* post that provides a `kde2d.weighted` function which is lightning fast and that we could try (see code at the bottom).

```
dens2 <- kde2d.weighted(x=df$x, y=df$y, w=proportions(df$dur), n=n) 
image(dens2, col=heat.colors(n, rev=TRUE))
```

[image]

However, the two versions look quite different, and I can't tell which is right, since I am not really an expert with this method. But at least there is a noticeable difference to the unweighted image:

### Unweighted image

```
dens0 <- MASS::kde2d(df$x, df$y, n=n)
image(dens0, col=heat.colors(n, rev=TRUE))
```

[image]

### Points

Still adding the points might be pointless, but you could run this line after `image`:

```
points(y ~ x, df, cex=proportions(dur)*2e3, col='green')
```

---

Taken from *r-help* (Ort 2006):

```
kde2d.weighted <- function(x, y, w, h, n=n, lims=c(range(x), range(y))) {
  nx <- length(x)
  if (length(y) != nx) 
    stop("data vectors must be the same length")
  gx <- seq(lims[1], lims[2], length=n)  ## gridpoints x
  gy <- seq(lims[3], lims[4], length=n)  ## gridpoints y
  if (missing(h)) 
    h <- c(MASS::bandwidth.nrd(x), MASS::bandwidth.nrd(y))
  if (missing(w)) 
    w <- numeric(nx) + 1
  h <- h/4
  ax <- outer(gx, x, "-")/h[1]  ## distance of each point to each grid point in x-direction
  ay <- outer(gy, y, "-")/h[2]  ## distance of each point to each grid point in y-direction
  z <- (matrix(rep(w,n), nrow=n, ncol=nx, byrow=TRUE)*
          matrix(dnorm(ax), n, nx)) %*% 
    t(matrix(dnorm(ay), n, nx))/(sum(w)*h[1]*h[2])  ## z is the density
  return(list(x=gx, y=gy, z=z))
}
```

Comment: Nice answer jay, though I'm not convinced the `kde2d.weighted` is producing the right result - it looks very different to your first 'inflated ' method which (unsurprisingly) matches the tidyr uncount method.

Comment: @AllanCameron yeah, I expressed my doubts in the answer. Maybe it attracts some expert that fixes `kde2d.weighted` which is probably flawed. We also could benefit from a faster alternative to `MASS::kde2d`, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks ! It works like a charm with sample data but when applying the method on the actual data set, I'm encountering memory limitation ! I might have to find a way around that

Comment: @user1969717 You could play around with the `n=`, the default is `25`, 1000 is very ambitious :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way round this is to use `tidyr::uncount` to replicate the rows of your data frame, using `dur` as weights:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(tidyr::uncount(df, dur), aes(x=x, y =y)) +
  stat_density2d(geom='raster', 
                 aes(fill=..count.., alpha=..count..), contour=FALSE) + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(size=dur), alpha=0.2, color="red") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="green", high="red") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0, 1) , guide="none") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

The effect is probably easier to see with the points removed:

```r
ggplot(tidyr::uncount(df, dur), aes(x=x, y =y)) +
  stat_density2d(geom='raster', 
                 aes(fill=..count.., alpha=..count..), contour=FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="green", high="red") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0, 1) , guide="none") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]